# OSX Error when install Rails: sqlite3 is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite

I've downloaded MacPorts and have it installed. Then, following the guide, I should upgrade the version of sqlite3 on my machine. I ran the following in terminal:

```
sudo port upgrade sqlite3
```

I received the following error: **Error: sqlite3 is not installed**

I've read online sqlite3 already exists in OSX then I ran the following in terminal:

```
which sqlite3
```

I received: **/usr/bin/sqlite3**

It indicates sqlite3 is in my system indeed. This line must be its path.

So: how can I connect the existing path to where it is requested in MacPorts?

Answer (score 0):

"The upgrade action upgrades installed ports and their dependencies when a Portfile in the repository has been updated after a port was installed."

http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.upgrade

You can't upgrade the Apple-installed sqlite. You must install the version MacPorts manages (which will probably be newer)

http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.install